# Using joist hangers to support a lean-to/skillion roof?

Tags: roof

I'm in the process of building a 14x16 tiny house with a lean-to/skillion slanted roof. I have the walls built, front wall is 12', back wall is 8'. I'm doing things a little different because I don't want an overhang in the front. I have scrap cuts of 2 by 4s attached to the sides of the studs on the tall side to hook the joist hangers to

[image]

My plan is to kerf/put a slit in the roof rafters so that they will sit flush on 90 degree joist hangers

[image]

My question is: Will this be structurally sound ?

It's such a small roof so I feel like it will be fine but I'd like to get some second opinions on this since it's not really the typical way to do these kind of slanted roofs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joist hangers are fine for this application. You'd want to notch the ends of the joists with a level cut so they rest properly in the hanger.

However, the blocks are a bit hokey. It's not great to hold things up with nails in shear like that with such small pieces. it would be better to simply put a ledger across the wall at joist height.

Answer (score 0):

Hard for me to tell the sizing, but look at the Simpson LRUZ hanger, which is designed for sloping rafters.

[Simpson catalog page] https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/w2t0azhgvv/C-C-2019-p114-115.pdf

Answer (score -1):

No. Over time, the joist will split at the cut. Also, the blocking is not adequate not to mention that the hanger nailing probably won't align with the blocking.

I would solve the issue using a hanger similar to LRUZ (already mentioned in the another answer) attached to a continuous 2x6 ledger face nailed to the studs.

We have no idea what the loads are so it isn't possible to give you the nailing requirements, etc.

Also, your 12' wall could be an issue depending on the member size, roof loads and wind loads.

Comment: Why is it not a problem to bird's mouth a rafter then? That's what I'm doing on the lower end for the overhang and that's very common practice. The bird's mouth at the other end is deeper than the notch/slit I'll be making at the top end.

Comment: It's common place at the bottom end where isn't an issue

It is unfortunately somewhat common at the top end although it is simply not acceptable. How 'bad' it is depends on a lot of factors including the load.

To put it into quick and simple terms, think of it this way, on the bottom your just removing some unused material. At the top, your cutting into the thickness of the member itself

Comment: This might help, bottom of the page. It's also in the codes. https://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/wood-construction-connectors/technical-notes/instructions-for-the-installer

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree it's not proper, not sure if I'm going to go ahead with it or not. My Home Depot doesn't have the sloped hangers they cost way more. I took a measurement and it would only reduce the height at the notch of the 2x6s by around 10% at the most. They only need to hold up some OSB and metal roofing, maybe rarely some snow. Either way I'll add the ledger board though.